# How to do basename on second field in a file and replace it in line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to get something like basename of second field in a file and replace it:

```
$ myfile=/var/lib/jenkins/myjob/myfile

$ sha512sum "$myfile" | tee myfile-checksum
$ cat myfile-checksum
deb32b1c7122fc750a6742765e0e54a821 /var/lib/jenkins/myjob/myfile
```

Desired output:

```
deb32b1c7122fc750a6742765e0e54a821 myfile
```

So people can easily do `sha512sum -c myfile-checksum` with no manual edits.

With sed or awk, that is how far i made it for now :)

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' myfile-checksum
sed -i "s|${value}|$(basename $value)|" myfile-checksum
```

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the described behaviour. `sha512sum` will print only the basename next to the hash, not the full name

Comment: @hek2mgl it prints the full path for me using bash on cygwin.

Comment: @EdMorton Because you passed the full path. If you navigate to the directory and call sha256sum with just the file's basename it will just print the basename along with the hash.

Comment: @hek2mgl But that's what the OP IS doing, passing the full path.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, but he should not since that leads to the result he complains about. Check my answer, I've explained how to use `sha256sum` correctly, in order to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the field separators to both spaces and slashes and print the first and last fields:

```
awk -F" |/" '{print $1, $NF}'
```

With your input:

```
$ awk -F" |/" '{print $1, $NF}' <<< "deb32b1c7122fc750a6742765e0e54a821 /var/lib/jenkins/myjob/myfile"
deb32b1c7122fc750a6742765e0e54a821 myfile
```

In case your filename contain spaces, do remove everything from the first field up to the last slash, as indicated by Ed Morton:

```
$ awk '{hash=$1; gsub(/^.*\//,""); print hash, $0}' <<< "deb32b1c7122fc750a6742765e0e54a821 /var/lib/jenkins/myjob/myfile with spaces"
deb32b1c7122fc750a6742765e0e54a821 myfile with spaces
```

Comment: echo $checksum | awk -F" |/" '{print $1, $NF}' | tee myfile perfect !! thanks :)

Comment: That's a useless processing. You just need to navigate to the folder of interest and execute `sha512sum` from there. The situation described in the question is not reproducible.

Comment: @Ed Morton in fact I added another version, so that my answer is complete. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`sha512sum` will simply use the file name you've passed to it - unchanged.

If you pass

```
sha512sum /path/to/file
```

it will give you:

```
123456..    /path/to/file
```

But if you:

```
pushd /path/to
    sha512sum file
popd
```

it will give you

```
123456..         file
```

---

If the filename is a variable you can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) like this:

```
pushd "${file%/*}"
    sha256sum "${file##*/}"
popd
```

or even

```
# cd will not change the PWD of the current shell since
# the command runs in a sub shell
(cd "${file%/*}"; sha256sum "${file##*/}")
```

Having that `$file` contains the filename, `${file%/*}` expands to the path without the filename and `${file##*/}` expands to the filename without the path.

Comment: Actually i'm passing variable which contains the full-path, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'sub(".*/",$1" ")' <<< "deb32b1c7122fc750a6742765e0e54a821 /var/lib/jenkins/myjob/myfile"
deb32b1c7122fc750a6742765e0e54a821 myfile
```

The will work for any file name except one that contains newlines. If you have that case let us know.